# How to make this if else-if statement into a short form in Java?

Tags: java

```
public static double eMED(int emo) {
    double result = 0;

    if (emo >= 40 && emo < 60) {
        result = upFunc(emo, 40, 60);
    } else if (emo > 60 && emo <= 80) {
        result = downFunc(emo, 60, 80);
    } else if (emo == 60) {
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: you can use direct return instead of use a variable, but you can shorter because you have 4 possb

Comment: I always prefer return in the end of the function. It's much more readable

Comment: Why do you want it shorter?  Looks like the perfect length to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code already looks short. You can't make it shorter. You can use ternary operator but the code becomes barely readable.

```
    return emo == 60 ? 1 
            : emo >= 40 && emo < 60 ? upFunc(emo, 40, 60) 
            : emo > 60 && emo <= 80 ? downFunc(emo, 60, 80) 
            : 0;
```

Answer (score -3):

use case it is short

**example :**

```
public class SwitchDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 8;
        String monthString;
        switch (month) {
            case 1:  monthString = "January";
                     break;
            case 2:  monthString = "February";
                     break;
            case 3:  monthString = "March";
                     break;
            case 4:  monthString = "April";
                     break;
            case 5:  monthString = "May";
                     break;
            case 6:  monthString = "June";
                     break;
            case 7:  monthString = "July";
                     break;
            case 8:  monthString = "August";
                     break;
            case 9:  monthString = "September";
                     break;
            case 10: monthString = "October";
                     break;
            case 11: monthString = "November";
                     break;
            case 12: monthString = "December";
                     break;
            default: monthString = "Invalid month";
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how a switch case is appropriate for this question?

Comment: case : 
Use if you want to compare one number or one case only

Comment: But if you want more than a comparison of more than one or more cases, there can be nothing shorter than what you use.

Comment: @GoldenCode For this particular question, switch/case would be almost entirely useless.  You'd need to list 41 separate cases, as well as the default.